# Does grep -r always search through files in the same order?

Tags: grep

When doing the `grep` recursive command to search a string within files:

```
grep -r "height:" *.txt
aaa.txt:height: 15
bbb.txt:height: 12
ccc.txt:height: 17
```

Can we safely assume that grep will ***always*** list files in the same order (i.e. alphanumeric) each time?

Comment: There are really two questions hiding in this; one around "-r" and one around globs.  The duplicate is only answering the glob part.  A full answer would also address the "-r" part, even if it's not what the OP was thinking about!

Comment: your command asks to search files ending in `.txt` and all files in directories ending in `.txt`. The order of the files (if no matching directories found), is determined by bash. bash expands the `*.txt` and passes the list to grep. Try echo `*.txt`. bash will do all the work, echo does next to nothing.